# Fourier series of function subject to conditions

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$F(x) = 0$ for $-2 \pi / k < t < 0;$

$F(x) = sin(kx)$ for $0 < t < 2 \pi / k$

I am really confused in how to find the Fourier series of this function, supposing it is periodic with period $4 \pi /k$

$$\int _{-2 \pi /k}^{2 \pi /k} F(x')cos(nkx')dx' = \int _{0}^{2 \pi /k} sin(kx')cos(nkx')dx'=0$$
$$\int _{-2 \pi /k}^{2 \pi /k} F(x')sin(nkx')dx' = \int _{0}^{2 \pi /k} sin(kx')sin(nkx')dx'=0$$

Since both integral are zero, the coefficients in the expansion would be zero too, but this is absurd. Where is my error?

Comment: The last integral is not 0 if $n = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misremembered the formula.

In fact, the Fourier series of a function $f$ with period $2l$ is

$$a_n=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l f(x)\cos\frac{n\pi}{l}xdx$$

$$b_n=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l f(x)\sin\frac{n\pi}{l}xdx$$

$$f\sim\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n\cos\frac{n\pi}{l}x+b_n\sin\frac{n\pi}{l}x)$$

So in your problem,

$$a_n=\frac{k}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi/k}\sin(kx)\cos(nkx/2)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(t)\cos(nt/2)dt=\begin{cases}
\frac{-4}{\pi(n^2-4)} &,n \text{ odd}\\
0 &,n \text{ even}\\
\end{cases}$$

$$b_n=\frac{k}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi/k}\sin(kx)\sin(nkx/2)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(t)\sin(nt/2)dt=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} &,n=2\\
0 &,\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f\sim \frac{1}{2}\sin(kx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-4}{\pi(4n^2-4n-3)}\cos((n-\frac{1}{2})kx)$$